From definition of derivative, find derivative of a function at a point
From my uni's textbook. From the definition of derivative, find the derivative at $x=0$ of $f$.
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\sin^2{x}\times\cos{\frac{5}{x}}+2x & x\neq 0\\ 
0 & x=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$
For the first function, as $x$ approaches $0$, the derivative $f'(0)$ is equal to 2.
$$\frac{sin(x)^2cos(\frac{5}{x})+2(x)}{x}=\frac{x.sin(x)^2cos(\frac{5}{x})}{x^2}+2=x.cos\frac{5}{x} +2=0+2=2$$
But, if we derive the second branch of $f$, which is $0$ then the derivatives don't meet.
Does that tell us that the derivative is a discontinuous function or should I conclude that the derivative doesn't exist there?

Do you know that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 1$ ?

@Sam, yes. I used that fact when calculating the derivative using the definition via limit.

@Sam, I added the way I calculated the derivative of the first function using limit asx approaches 0

These are not two functions whose derivative can be calculated separately. It is one single function that satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(a\neq0)=\sin^2(a)\cos(5/a)+2a$. Its derivative at 0 is
$$f'(0):=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x},$$
where $x\neq0$ before taking the limit. So you're calculating the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2(x)\cos(5/x)+2x}{x}=2$. This limit exists, so by definition $f$ is differentiable at 0. The definition of the derivative at a point does not care about how the derivative looks at other points.
If the derivative at $x\neq0$ happens to not converge to the same number, that just means that the derivative is discontinuous, nothing more

So then the answer will be that the derivative at x=0 is 2? So if we looked at function $f'(x)$ where the RHS and LHS imits don't meet as x approaches 0 - it only means that the function $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at x=0?

Sorry, you just answered my question.
